# CSS style in navigation bar affecting links in content

Tags: css

I created navigation bar  with hyperlinks to other pages

CSS code:

```
a
{
display:block;
width:120px;
color:brown;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
background-color:yellow;
padding:4px;
transition-property: background;
transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

However, this now affects other links which are outside the navigation bar. How do i separate links in navigation bar from those located in content's text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the styles to be applied only for links inside navigation bar. You'll need a selector for the navigation bar. For example if it is a nav tag you can use `nav a{}` or if it has a class of navigator then .`navigator a{}` or similarly an id `#navigator a{}`